# Change color of background on login screen

Tags: login-screen

EDIT: I should mention I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 with Cinnamon, though I could switch to Unity to change, then switch back.

Alright, so I changed the background on my login screen (the cheap way, by just renaming my image to "/usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png"), and the color of the ubuntu loading splash (by editing /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.script). These both work perfectly fine.

The problem: Between the loading splash and the login screen, there's a brief period while my background image loads, where the background is just the default purple color, with the white dot overlay. I'd like to know how I can change the color of this (and possibly get rid of the dots too).

Comment: you probably need to edit your initrd. Try rebuilding it first `sudo update-initramfs -u` and reboot

Comment: I've called 'sudo update initramfs -u' and rebooted multiple times (that's also required for chaning the splash color)

Answer (score 0):

On clicking change background (right click on background) The opening color apears right below  your wallpaper. change that to the default color of your liking. (A note about this is that im running ubuntu on crouton so I do not have a login screen upon opening this up. so I do not know if this worked.)

Comment: ^doesn't work (My login background never changed when I changed my Unity background either)

Comment: yeah, this doesn't work. I've already changed the default to black in my user settings and it's still purple